# Pass List<child> as argument?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to create a method that serializes lists of different childs. Each child gets his own XML file. Doing this for a single object was easy:

> interface ISerializable
>       {
>       }
>
> ```
> public class Item : ISerializable
> {
>     public string name { get; set; }
>     public int number { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class Weapon : ISerializable
> {
>     public string name { get; set; }
>     public int damage {get; set;}
> }
> ```

```
public static void SerializeToXML(ISerializable child)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(child.GetType());
            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(textWriter, child);
            }
        }
```

I can put anything derived from `ISerializable` into the serialize method to get a desired result. However when give `List<ISerializable>` as possible argument it does not compile `Cannot convert List<item> to List<ISerializable>`. Anyway to solve this?

```
public static void SerializeListToXML(List<ISerializable> listToXML)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(listToXML.GetType());
            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(textWriter, listToXML);
            }
        }
```

The base reason i'm doing this is to get XML templates of much larger structures so i an manually add XML to load into my program. I figured i would benefit from creating a serializer first so i have the correct XML structure to start with. Perhaps this can come in handy later down the line for saving user data too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SerializeListToXML` should take an `IEnumerable<ISerializable>` instead of a `List<Item>`.

A `List<Item>` cannot be casted to `List<ISerializable>`. If you could to that, then you'd be able to add any `ISerializable` to the list, not just Items. With an `IEnumerable<>`, you cannot modify the collection - only iterate over it. Since `SerializeListToXML` does not need to modify the collection, it can accept an `IEnumerable<ISerializable>`, which is less restrictive. Please see the following section and sub-sections about covariance and contravariance: [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

Comment: This does seem to work, thank you. Not sure why you got the downvote, perhaps you have to elaborate the answer some more.